# Why do I get an error when evaluating $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{d\theta}{1+\sin^{2}\theta}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Using the trigonometric identity: $$\cos 2\theta = 1 +  \sin^{2} \theta$$

I get that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta}$$

Then using a property of integrals, I get: $$\int_{-\pi}^{0}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta} + \int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta}$$

Now since $\cos \theta$ is an even function, shouldn't I get that $$\int_{-\pi}^{0}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta}=\int_{\pi}^{0}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta}?$$

But then $$\int_{\pi}^{0}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta}=-\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta}$$

Which would mean that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta}=0$$

But this is not the case as $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\dfrac{d\theta}{\cos 2\theta}=\pi\sqrt{2}$$

So I was wondering where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing? Also, this problem comes from a complex analysis course, so I'm not sure if I'm getting an error because I'm applying incorrect methods.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189)
-- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is
distributed evenly over the questions.  See
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/290189) for more information.
Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your "identity" would mean that $\cos2\theta\ge1$ for all $\theta$.

Comment: Note that $1+\sin^2(\theta) > 0$ but $\cos(2 \theta)$ can be negative...

Comment: Another error: since $\cos2\theta$ is an even function, you get that $\int_{-\pi}^0=\int_0^\pi=-\int_\pi^0$.

Comment: $$\begin{align}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1}{1+\sin^2(\theta)}\,d\theta&=4\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{1+\sin^2(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\&=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2(\theta)}{1+2\tan^2(\theta)}\,d\theta\\\\&=\left.\left(\frac{\arctan(\sqrt 2 \tan(\theta))}{\sqrt2}\right)\right|_0^{\arctan\pi/2}\\\\&=\sqrt 2\pi\end{align}$$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I thought that even functions "absorb" the negative in the argument. So then $\int_{-\pi}^{0}=\int_{\pi}^{0}?$

Comment: You thought wrong.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: do the properties of even and odd functions change when integrating?

Comment: I urge you to make a drawing and look at what it means to integrate. And bear in mind that $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$, always, and that if you integrate a positive function, the integral is positive if $a<b$ in $\int_a^b$. So if the integrand is even and positive, then $\int_{-\pi}^0$ is positive, but $\int_\pi^0$ is certainly not.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I get it now. I just used that $\int_{-\pi}^{0} + \int_{0}^{\pi}=2\int_{0}^{\pi} \rightarrow \int_{-\pi}^{0} = \int_{0}^{\pi} \rightarrow \int_{-\pi}^{0}=\int_{0}^{\pi}=-\int_{\pi}^{0}$. I'll do the drawing to brush up fundamentals though.

Comment: @MarkViola: why are the limits of integration changed?

Comment: @K.M Symmetry was exploited.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\cos 2\theta = 1- 2 \sin^2 \theta \neq 1+\sin^2 \theta.$

Observe that $$\begin {align*} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac {d\theta} {1 + \sin^2 \theta} & = 2 \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {d \theta} {1 + \sin^2 \theta}. \end{align*}$$

Also since $\sin^2 (\pi - \theta) = \sin^2 \theta$ so we have $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {d \theta} {1 + \sin^2 \theta} = 2 \int_{0}^{\frac {\pi} {2}} \frac {d \theta} {1 + \sin^2 \theta}.$$ Therefore $$\begin{align*} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac {d \theta} {1 + \sin^2 \theta} & = 4 \int_{0}^{\frac {\pi} {2}} \frac {d \theta} {1 + \sin^2 \theta}.\\ & = 4 \int_{0}^{\frac {\pi} {2}} \frac {\sec^2 \theta\ d\theta} {\sec^2 \theta + \tan^2 \theta} \\ & = 4 \int_{0}^{\frac {\pi} {2}} \frac {\sec^2 \theta\ d\theta} {1 + 2 \tan^2 \theta}. \end{align*}$$

Now use the substitution $u=\sqrt 2 \tan \theta.$ Then $du = \sqrt 2 \sec^2 \theta\ d\theta.$ Therefore the integral becomes $$2 \sqrt 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {du} {1+u^2} = 2 \sqrt 2\ \arctan u\ \Biggr|_0^{\infty} = 2 \sqrt 2 \times \frac {\pi} {2} = \sqrt 2 \pi.$$

Comment: It doesn't worry you that the integral of a strictly positive integrand turns out to be zero?

Comment: Yeah! I also feel that I have done some serious mistake. But what exactly it is @Lord Shark the Unknown? Can you point it out.?

Comment: Hint: $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{1+\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt2\pi$$

Comment: You have to be careful with the change of variable $u=f(\theta)$ where the function $f$ is not bijective: $u=\tan\theta$ on $[0,\pi]$, that's not gonna do it. The correct way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution Note that when you write $\theta=g(u)$, the situation is much more friendly w.r.t. bijectivity.